# Does Spark recompute dataframes after a show

Tags: apache-spark

I am curious about how Spark handles compute stages.

May be I can give a few examples:

```scala
val df1 = stage1(df)
val df2 = stage2(df1)
df2.show(10)
val df3 = stage3(df2)
```

How does Spark handle the `show` here ? Does it compute `stage1` and `stage2` twice, once for the show, one for `stage3`. This would mean that show() slow down the processes

Does the use have control over what get persisted and what does not ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show is an Action. Assuming there is an Action after stage3, then recomputation will occur.

If there was no show, then not.

Caching on df2 would mean no recomputation in your example, specifically.

Comment: You're saying that `df2` will recomputed twice if there an action after `stage3`. Do you recommend using `df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)` to persist ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that, I use .cache. Real thing to consider is what happens if the Actions are executed concurrent, not yet tried that. But I suspect .cache or equivalent required.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'm surprised that Spark does not handle the computation more efficiently.

Comment: It is an action. Period. Yes I know that blurb.

Comment: In fact the question is a little contrived. Given that most stages will be transforms, joins, groupings, it will be an Action. By defintion stuff going to the driver it is considered an Action.

Comment: `show` is not an action in that is doesn't always guarantee the compute of the entire underlying RDD/DataFrame/Dataset. Here is the list of actions: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions If you were to do `val df2 = stage2(df1).cache()` and then `df2.show()`, `df2` is not completely cached but at least part of it is, depending on what you did in `stage2()`. I say "depending" because if you performed an `.orderBy(...)` in `stage2()` then it may be completely cached. Check out the Spark UI and look at the `Storage` tab.

Comment: @thebluephantom It's classified as an action, yes, but it acts way differently than other actions. If you perform `val foo = spark.read.parquet("file.parquet").cache()` and then you do `foo.show()` only part of foo is cached because `show()` does not perform an action on the entire DataFrame. So, yes, you are correct. It is an action but `val foo = spark.read.parquet("file.parquet").cache().count()` will cause the entire dataframe to be cached. `.show()` doesn't do that and I felt the way that you answered the question did not clarify that very important distinction.

Comment: We agree to differ, I get your point, but you do not get mine.